# Callback to Class (non-instance)

Tags: java, oop, callback, lwjgl

LWJGL 3 uses a callback system to handle inputs, like so:

```
public class Main
{

    ...

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback = new GLFWKeyCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
            {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

However, I do not wish to be handling my inputs in the middle of code for another purpose.

I can extend a class with GLFWKeyCallback and pass an instance of that class in to glfwSetKeyCallback(), however I am not executing that function from in an instance. It is running from a static function (main). I do not wish to move the code from main in to an instanced object since it conflicts with my coding style and that will stress me out and I'll cave and undo it eventually.

The way I have it now is like so:

```
public class Main
{

    private static GLFWKeyCallbackProxy glfwKeyCallbackProxy;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, glfwKeyCallbackProxy);
    }

}

public class GLFWKeyCallbackProxy extends GLFWKeyCallback
{

    @Override
    public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
    {
        // Communicate back to Main
    }

}
```

I really dislike this also, as GLFWKeyCallbackProxy is now implementing part of the game, not just being used by the game. I believe it works against good OOP structure, and it has tight coupling.

Ideally my solution would want to be somewhat equivalent to this hypothetical code:

```
public class Main extends GLFWKeyCallback
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, ???);
    }

    @Override
    public static void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
    {
        // This function now resides along side the code dealing with the rest of the game.
    }

}
```

Essentially I want the callback functions to treat the static class level functions as though is was an instance, even though it isn't.

How would you go about achieving this, or will I have to resort to some tight coupling like with my solution above?

Edit: I forgot to mention, in whatever solution, I will need to have access to the internals of GLFWKeyCallback. Let's assume that I cannot access those internals purely by reference (through publics or getters/setters).

Solution I ended up taking:

```
public class Game
{
    static long window;

    public static void keyboardInvoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
    {

    }

    public static void mouseInvoke(long window, int button, int action, int mods)
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, GLFWKeyCallback(Game::keyboardInvoke));
        glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, GLFWMouseButtonCallback(Game::mouseInvoke));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first recommendation would be to start getting used with "handling my inputs in the middle of code for another purpose".

Now, if you really don't want to do that, then you can try this:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, new GLFWKeyCallbackProxy());
    }

    class GLFWKeyCallbackProxy extends GLFWKeyCallback
    {
        @Override
        public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
        {
            // Communicate back to Main
        }
    }
}
```

Your inner class will have access to the members of the containing class, so you should be fine.

But the recommendation that I would most strongly urge you to consider is to move on to Java 8, where you will be able to do something like this:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        glfwSetKeyCallback( window, Main::invoke );
    }

    void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
    {
        // Communicate back to Main
    }
}
```

...so invoke() becomes a member method of Main, and everything is beautiful.

Also, one final recommendation, unrelated to the problem at hand: Never write any important code in static main().  The first (and only) thing that main() should do is instantiate an object and pass control to it.

Comment: That is a good idea, I prefer that so far, and I can probably live with that. I'd prefer it not be in a class as it's not something intended to be reused, or swapped out, etc. I don't want to force that singularly through singletons/some pattern either. But I suppose I may be at the mercy of the language limits here. Thanks a lot. I'll continue waiting for other suggestions for a small while.

Comment: Yes, of course, by all means wait to see what others say, there are lots of brilliant people on StackOverflow.

Comment: (I just saw your edits) Well, the Java 8 thing would only work if `GLFWKeyCallback` was a single-method interface, so it turns out that it does not apply in this specific case.

Comment: I totally forgot Java 8 was a thing!! I haven't actually looked at the new stuff, I'm excited to see what that Main::invoke thing is. Edit: excited even if it's not solving the problem.

Comment: I do disagree with your final point though (I understand if it be "the" way to do things in Java/OOP). I just think it ends up being an extra level of unnecessary abstraction/indirection. I did try it out that way before, but I ended up getting very stressed over it looking wrong and I deleted it.

Comment: It depends on your perspective of course.  For many people, at some point what ends up counting most is not having to switch between frames of mind, in this case the static frame of mind and the instance frame of mind.  Dealing with only one of the two frames of mind yields peace of mind, which is considered to be a very good thing by many. And since you *have to* use instances, the instance frame of mind cannot be avoided, therefore the static frame of mind is the one that has to go.

Comment: After revisiting the instanced version I got a little more comfortable with it. However I discovered GLFW.java had a SAM interface inside of it, and also a method to create a GLFWKeyCallback instance by passing in a SAM interface. I have decided to go this route instead and presume there is no information inside those callbacks that I'll need (It is a callback, that wouldn't even be normal would it?). I can also rename the functions. Code ends up like glfwSetKeyCallback(window, GLFWKeyCallback(Game::invoke));
        glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, GLFWMouseButtonCallback(Game::invoke));